# How many possible solutions are there in 4 number game?

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

$4$ number game consist of $4$ random number from $0$ to $9$. The goal is to make the result equal to $24$. There are only operation four operation possible, addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division. So my question is out of all $4$ set number how many of those have a solution.

All the number must be used. For example if '$8937$' is given. Even though $(8*(9/3))$ is equal to 24. This solution did not count as number '$7$' is not used.

Please don't forget about addition and subtraction. And one configuration can have multiple solution too. For example '$6843$'. We can use $(8-6)*3*4$ or $(8/4+6)*3$.

> > Can you explain it in a formal way, please?

Comment: The title and body seem to be about two completely different questions. The title asks for the number of solutions, whereas if I understand correctly in the body you seem to be trying to find the number of problems. Which is it?

Comment: I want to find all possible solution. So I first limit the number of possible configuration to limit number of possible solution in that set. I'm sorry about that

Comment: Order is not important. For example. If I was given 6467 and 7664, I will still using 6*4*(7-6) to get to 24 regardless of order

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't understand. What do you mean by "limit"? How are you limiting the numbers of configurations and of solutions? Do you want to find all possible solutions for a particular problem, or for all possible problems? How does the numbers being random enter into all this?

Comment: I want to find number of all possible solution. I will fix it right away

Comment: Must you use every number?

Comment: Ok so order is not important. But you are still missing the cases like 1,1,2,2. You have not counted them in case 2.

Comment: You must use all the number. For example if I have 8319. Then If I use $8$*$3$*$1$ is equal to $24$ but there is a 9 left. So this is not a valid solution

Comment: Yeah, I completely forgot about that...

Comment: The only sensible way to answer your question (how many of the sets of numbers can give 24) is to write code.

Comment: If you want to find the number of all possible solutions, I don't understand a) why you're trying to count the number of problem configurations in the question, and b) why you introduce randomness into the question. There seems to be no role for the random selection of the problem configuration in the actual question.

Comment: Yeah, I first thought of a probability in finding a ration between a set that have solution by set of all possible configuration.

Comment: @user349470  The condition that all numbers must be used, should be added to the question. The data must **not** be split in two: question and comments.